# Mysql to Postgresql conversion tool in Java

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

Is there a Java tool that can convert mysql dump into postgresql dump available.

Googling got me this, https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres. Which is a ruby gem.
In my current development environment installing Ruby is not allowed.

The versions used

- Mysql 5.1
- Postgres 8.2

Note: `mysqldump --compatible=postgresql`  didnt work!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, PostgreSQL 8.2 is ancient and [unsupported](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Upgrade urgently. Read the release notes for each .0 version to find out about any compatibility issues you may face.

As for the conversion, you should generally do it in two phases. Convert and load the schema, *then* convert and load the data.

Generally automated tools won't do a good job converting database schemas. You should do a schema-only dump, run a conversion tool over it then hand-edit and hand-check it before loading it into PostgreSQL.

Once you have a schema that looks sane, do a data-only dump from MySQL and try loading that into  a PostgreSQL instance with your converted schema loaded in it. `mysqldump --compatible=postgresql` may do a better job, though you'll probably need additional flags too.

If you try it and still don't have any luck, consider following up with more detail. Report exact error messages not just "doesn't work" if you follow up.

Comment: thank u for the info. Since my schema is small and didnt have much time, I did a manual conversion.. Just asked for GK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider downloading the [advanced server](http://enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server/downloads) and use the built-in migration toolkit.

However, you should as Craig said - upgrade to a supported version of postgresql.